# Edittext inputtype constant value doesnot match

Tags: android, validation, android-layout, android-edittext

In android xml file im using editext as

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/email"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="33dp"
  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
  android:hint="Enter your mail id" />
```

In java file while validating that editext.

```
if(editextobj.getInputType()==InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS){

}
```

or

```
if(getInputType()==(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)){
```

}

this condition is not working since `editextobj.getInputType()` returns 33 whereas developer document gives `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` constant value as 32

How to validate inputype programatically?

Comment: funny solution:: use editextobj.getInputType() -1

Comment: @saa editextobj.getInputType() -1 working only in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

The following is happening:
`InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS` value is: 32.
`InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` value is: 1.

the (|) is a bitwise OR operation. It's doing modification at the binary level:

*Decimal:*  32|1 results in 33
*Binary:*  100000|1 results in 100001 which is 33 in decimal.

`editextobj.getInputType()` value is 33

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. 32 stays for [TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS). Also it's a flag, so you should test it like this. See [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) example(at the top under class overview) for more details.

```
if(editextobj.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS == 1){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to test each flag separately, e.g.:

```
if ( ( editextobj.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS) != 0)
{
     // This is an email address!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(editextobj.getInputType() == (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS + 1)) {....}
```