# EditText getInputType Value result is different from what I expected

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm confused while using `edittext.getInputType()`

I set my xml InputType to the following:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email_address"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/emailAddressActionId"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

I have an if condition in my java class to verify whether or not my editText input type value is equal to TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS:

```
if ((editText.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS)) {
            // logic code execute
        }
```

**Result:**
While debugging, values are returning the following:

[image: editText getInputType Value]

And from the documentation, textEmailAddress value is 21.
[TextView android:inputType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

**I cant' figure what I'm currently doing wrong?**

Comment: @H.Brooks the if condition itself is not being executed, so its logic is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: This question is a duplicate to another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781087/edittext-inputtype-constant-value-doesnot-match but the other question did not have an exact answer. I provided a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47186831/5544859

Comment: The InputType values defined in documentation are in hexadecimal, but the value you get is in decimal.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477817/android-get-edittext-input-type-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

The  **TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS** flag must be tested separately,
this way:

```
if ((editText.getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS) != 0) {
        // logic code execute
    }
```